# What is Apache's OpenSSL and why does one server have it but another not

Tags: apache, ssl, curl, https, openssl

I'm working with two servers; one localhost one on the web. Both are http; I don't have an SSL certificate installed on either.

When I'm trying to make a Curl request to an https url (in this case the Facebook API), one of the servers works and the other doesn't. The CURL error is "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate." Upon investigation, I noticed that `$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]` outputs something different on the two servers.

**Server 1, which works with CURL to https**

$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

**Server 2, which *doesn't* work with CURL to https**

$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = Apache

I'm guessing that the fact that the second server has no mention of OpenSSL may have something to do with the error? Is that possible? What would I need to do to get OpenSSL on that server? Why would the first server be able to "find issuer certificate" when I don't have an SSL cert installed on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing a request with curl to an external server the problem is completely unrelated to the web server software you are running locally, i.e. you don't even need to run a local web server at all. It only depends on the certificate the external server sends back to curl and if the necessary root CA can be found in the trust store of curl.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying that the problem is on Facebook's end? Why would it work on one of my servers but not the other, then?

Comment: @Pete: no, I'm saying that "... and if the necessary root CA can be found in the trust store of curl". Since the certificates curl gets from facebook are probably the same on both systems it thus must be the other thing, i.e different configuration for the trust store of curl.

Comment: Ah okay, I *think* I understand. Does this sound correct: each server has a configuration/file (called a trust store?) that allows them to verify the authenticity of the certificate that Facebook sends over. Since Facebook's is failing, it's probably a problem with my configuration. Is that correct? Or am I way off base? Thanks so much for your help thus far!

Comment: @Pete: yes, that's about it.